# Why does this reducer return a promise? despite my use of Async?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to send a async get request to my server and get back data, the problem is I keep getting back a promise despite awaiting the data. Not sure why?

```
type HttpMethod = "get" | "post" | "put";

const initialState: any = [];
async function reducer(state: any, action: any) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "get":
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:3001/${action.payload.dataToFetch}`,
          {
            params: { data: action.payload.params },
          }
        );

        return await response;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
  }
}

export function useGlobalAxios(method: HttpMethod, dataToFetch: string,params?: unknown) {

  const [requests, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

  useEffect(() => {

    function get(){

        switch (method){
            case "get":
                console.log("in method")
                dispatch({type: "get", payload:{dataToFetch:dataToFetch, params:params} })
            }
        }

        get()
        
  }, [dataToFetch])

  return requests
}
```

Note: I tried adding the async to the get function in my useEffect, but it didn't work.

Comment: A function marked as `async` will always return a Promise.

Comment: Once one part of the code flow relies on asynchronous code (no matter if Promise or callback-based), all the following up/dependent code has to handle the result also asynchronously. So `reducer` will always either return a Promise or has to call a callback once it is finished.

Comment: Because that's (more or less) the definition of an `async` function: It returns a promise ...

Comment: @t.niese yes but if await the result, shouldn't the code the comes after the await, wait until the await is resolved?

Comment: @Muath_01 An `await` can only be used in an `async` function, and it only affects the code that _"belongs"_ directly to that function. So the only code following the `await response` is the `return` (as a side note: the `await` at `return await response` is superfluous). For the caller of `reducer` the only relevant thing is that it is an `async` function and therefore always returns a Promise.

Answer (score 0):

You are awaiting the axios response promise, but your async `reducer` function also returns a promise:
The `reducer` function needs to return immediately, even if the response is not available yet, so the `reducer` *has to* return another promise.

#### Wrong solution:

So you would theoretically also need to await the `requests` as well, and make `useGlobalAxios` asynchronous, and await that as well.

#### Right solution:

But you shouldn't use a reducer to invoke a network request anyway. [A reducer should be pure](https://react.dev/learn/extracting-state-logic-into-a-reducer#writing-reducers-well).

Instead you should make the request inside the `useEffect` *(or even better in some event handler, if possible)*. (You can still write a `fetchMyData` function, but not as a reducer.)

A reducer should - generally speaking - be used to "consolidate" available data, but not "generate" or request data.

So an action type should not be like "request-data", but should be more like "integrate-received-data-into-my-state".

#### Example:

```js
// ...
switch( method ){
  case "get":
    fetchMyData.then(
      data => dispatch({
        type: 'add-data-to-state',
        payload: data
      })
    );
}
```